# How do I automatically connect to the slave if the master goes down using redisio cookbook

Tags: redis

I am using [redisio cookbook](https://github.com/brianbianco/redisio/) to install a redis service.

I made my configuration [following these steps](https://github.com/brianbianco/redisio/#install-redis-and-setup-two-instances-on-the-same-server-on-different-ports-with-one-slaved-to-the-other-through-a-role-file).

```
node.default[:redisio][:default_settings][:requirepass] = 'redis'

node.default['redisio']['servers'] = [
    {'port' => '6379'},
    {'port' => '6380', 'slaveof' => { 'address' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => '6379' }}
]

include_recipe 'redisio::install'
include_recipe 'redisio::enable'
```

Whell, in the host machine everythings is fine, the two service (6379, 6380) were installed.

But my problems if this:

When I stop the master service (6379).

```
sudo service redis6379 stop
Stopping ...
Redis stopped
```

And I try to connect again, I expect a respond from the slave:

```
redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused not connected>
```

What else do I need to configure to get a respond from the slave?

Answer (score 2):

If I guess right, your question is: "How do I automatically connect to the slave if the master goes down". In your example, you are connecting to the default port, which is 6379, which is down, which you cannot connect to.

You need a seperate broker process for this: [Redis Sentinel](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel).

Redis Sentinel promotes the slave to master when needed. Your redis client should connect to redis sentinel (a third port), so your requests can be rerouted. Most client libraries support redis sentinel.

Hope this helps, TW